# MatLab:Generate N pseudo-random numbers with a Poisson distribution having mean M and total T where N,M, and T are user defined

Tags: matlab, random, poisson

I’d like to be able to generate in MatLab a sequence of *N* pseudo-random numbers with a Poisson distribution having mean *M*.  The sum of the *N* numbers should be *T*.  *N*, *M*, and *T* are always positive or zero and would be user specified parameters to any function.

Obviously, if *T* is small relative to *N* it is likely that there will be problems achieving a total of T. In that case the function could just return the values *T* and then *N*-1 zeros or an error code. However, it is highly likely that in most cases *T*>>*N*.

I have been trying variations based on the method of generating random numbers with a given distribution provided at http://matlabtricks.com/post-44/generate-random-numbers-with-a-given-distribution and trying various normalizations at each step but have not been successful.

Comment: I don't think it is not possible to have _independent_ Poisson variables with a prescribed sum. Perhaps not even _dependent_, because a Poisson random variable can be arbitrarily large. Tampering with the sum will spoil the distribution

Comment: Ok, I understand what you are saying.  Perhaps there may be a way towards a solution if the values of the pseudo-random numbers are bounded to be within (say) 6 standard deviations of the mean.  (Value of 6{\sigma} derived from Gaussian approximation approach.) Obviously, something somewhere (probably external to the function) is going to have to check if T can be reached with that condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to approximate what you want by using [multinomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution).

If you use Wikipedia notation, then `k=N`, `n=T` and p<sub>i</sub>=M/T. Poisson distribution has distinctive property of mean equal to variance, but if your parameters  are such that p<sub>i</sub> is small, then mean np<sub>i</sub> would be quite close to variance np<sub>i</sub>(1-p<sub>i</sub>). Sum would be automatically (by property of multinomial) equal of T.

Multinomial sampling in Matlab is done using [mnrmd function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/mnrnd.html).

UPDATE

Wrt comment, lets consider `N` sampled values v<sub>i</sub>, and write their sum

Sum(i=1...N) v<sub>i</sub> = T

Lets compute mean value of the left and right side of this equation.

Sum(i=1...N) E(v<sub>i</sub>) = E(T) = T

On the right side, mean value of constant is constant itself. On the left side we have

Sum(i=1...N) E(v<sub>i</sub>) = Sum(i=1...N) M = N*M = T

Therefore, M=T/N and p<sub>i</sub>=M/T=1/N.

Comment: That looks promising but, sorry, I'm being a bit stupid today and can't see how in MatLab p<sub>i</sub> can equal the constant M/T for all i if the sum of all p<sub>i</sub> must equal 1.  Testing the function in MatLab suggests this may be a typo for 1/N - is that correct?

Comment: @AlfredPennyworth. It is the same, please check update

Comment: @AlfredPennyworth It also means, given `T` and `N`, `M` cannot be independent value

Comment: Understood. That confirms my fears about the original question. I'll use the multinomial distribution approach you have explained. Many thanks.

Comment: @AlfredPennyworth You're welcome. Just remember, there are quite a few discrete distribution which has property of sum of samples being equal to fixed value. F.e. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet-multinomial_distribution, it is more complex than multinomial one, more parameters, and less Poissonish so to speak, but if multinomial is not working for you, there are for sure alternatives